# setting Title for navigation bar in xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have created a navigation controller programmatically,

```
        //Creating AddViewController Object
        addViewController *addView = [[addViewController alloc]init];
        UINavigationController *addViewControl = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];

        [addViewControl.view addSubview:addView.view];

        [self presentModalViewController:addViewControl animated:YES];
```

But when i add self.title = @"Title" in addViewController class. it is not displaying.

i tried with the following,

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"Title";

self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Title";
```

But it's not displaying Title.

I think it is possible to do with setting a label. but the above one is direct method.

Any Idea..

Comment: The question is WHEN are you setting that title. It has to be done within or before viewWillAppear is called on that freshly displayable viewController.

Comment: I'm with @Till - from the apple docs - "Use the initWithTitle: method to create a navigation item specifying the item’s title. The item cannot be represented on the navigation bar without a title." ie it needs setting first

Comment: @Anthony: i am not using any xib file for setting title and nib name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try initializing your navigation controller this way:

```
UINavigationController *addViewControl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addView];
[self presentModalViewController:addViewControl animated:YES];
//[addView release];
//[addViewControl release]; // uncomment these two lines if not using ARC
```

And then set the `title` property of your `addViewController` class in the `viewWillAppear` method.

Answer (score 14):

You should assign the title to the `addView` like `addView.title = @"Title";`

Another way to do it is `self.navigationItem.title = @"Title";`

Answer (score 6):

In the viewController class: 
`[self setTitle:@"title"];` or `self.title=@"title";`

Answer (score 6):

This seem to work fine for me

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Title";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your navigation controller isn't correctly setup:

```
UINavigationController *addViewControl = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:addView];
// delete this line: [addViewControl.view addSubview:addView.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working on an app that I'm creating:

```
[self.navigationItem setTitle:@"title here"];
```